# How to create a product image on Magento Api using Ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, magento

I am try to upload a image on magento API using Ruby.

This is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
require 'base64'

WSDL_URL = 'http://teeshop.chandru/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1'

soap = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(WSDL_URL).create_rpc_driver

session = soap.login('*********','*********')


a = File.read('image/CP0760-01.jpg')
enc = Base64.encode64(a)

create_image = { 'file' => {"name" => "CP0760-01.jpg", "content" => enc,"mime" => 'image/jpeg'}, "label" => "kids cloths","position" => 0, "types" => ["image,""small_image", "thumbnail" ], "exclude" => 0 }

product_image = soap.call('catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate',session,'CP0760 (P.34)',creeate_image,1,'sku')
```

When I run this code I got this error:

> The image contents is not valid base64 data. (SOAP::FaultError)

Is there any solution for my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i encode the image, it put the newline character at the end of line.This newline character create the problem. Magento needs the encoded image without the newline character.
So remove the newline character and run the code again it will work.

Its Works for me!